# GWT CK EDITOR - Rendering issue

Tags: java, gwt, ckeditor

I am using gwt-ckeditor in my application. I am using **GWT 2.5** and I have embedded **CKEDITOR** in GWT. I have some fields in form containing CKEditor as well. When I navigate from one form to another, it does not sustain its value. I dont want to save it. But I want to sustain it atleast for my validations to get complete. How can I acheive this functionality ? Please let me know. As Whenever it is getting detached it is losing its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I was also facing the same issue. **CKeditor** is actually extended from **IFrame** and that is why when it is detached from the form or widget, it will loose all the information. To sustain its value , you have to manually code it.

```
private String ckValue ;

CkEditor ckeditor = new CkEditor(new CkConfig());
ckeditor.addAttachHandler(new AttachHandler(){
       public void onAttach(Event value){
             setCkValue(value);
       }
});

public void setCkValue(String ckValue){
      this.ckValue = ckValue;
}

public String getCkValue(){
      return ckValue;
}
```